# Highlighting with jquery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highlight

I am newbie in programming and I have a question that has been asked many times in the past. I need to implement highlight in some fashion. I have seen a jquery plugin ( SearchHighlight). Jquery is using selectors. To be honest I don't whant to use them. What I need is to "feed" the plugin the string to be highlighted and the string that holds the search words via variables ex.

```
var searchterms = 'lolo loli let';
var searchstring = ' Lolo loves loli and .... Blah, blah';
var highlightedstring = '';

// SearchHighlight plugin

highlightedstring return;
```

If the above is not possible is there a way in pure JavaScript to do substring highlighting?

With respect,

Tom

Greece

Answer (score 0):

The concept around highlighting is to grab the html from the container where you're searching an wrap the word(s) found with tags that you can style. Simple example with just one word, but this could be extended with an array of words.

```
function highlight(word, content) {
    var html = $(content).html();
    var re = new RegExp(word, 'gi');
    $(content).html(html.replace(re, '<code>$&</code>'));
}

highlight('pleasure', '#content');
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/hdYmb/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't need exactly that. I don't need to grab the html from the element content but I want to pass into the jquery the content as string variable.